# Direct Ethernet connection won't work and WiFi hotspot setup doesn't work fast enough

Tags: laptop, ethernet, gaming

Me and my brother have always been gamers. We like to play multiplayer games together on computer but sometimes it becomes unbearable through our method now. We've tried setting up a direct connection through an Ethernet cord (cat5e) but neither of our laptops will detect that's its within the port after being plugged in. I've updated the drivers on both and the cord is still not being detected. We have no internet or router so we've used a "ghost" hotspot through an old tablet that has the option for one. We've tried other Ethernet cables and none will be detected. The ports are enabled on both and troubleshooting does nothing. The lag through the tablet has become unbearable to sometimes making games unplayable. We're both using Toshiba laptops (don't know how to find exact info anyone needs) with a windows 8.1 operating system. They're both pretty recent (2013). As for the tablet I have no idea about the make or model but it runs on Android Kernel. I just have two questions. How would I fix the Ethernet ports and play a direct connection multiplayer game through this connection. Or how would I make a new faster ghost hotspot or boost the one I have (I'm sorry for vague info if you need more please try to list directions to find makes/models/etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your ethernet ports are not broken or in need of a driver upgrade, you probably need an ethernet switch. Rather than plugging laptop to laptop, plug laptop to switch and laptop to switch (two cables.) Even an old 100 Mbit "fast ethernet" will be faster than most WiFi connections in practice, but 1 Gbit switches are not terribly expensive in small sizes.